# Relative references, recoaring macro, VBA

Tags: excel, vba7

I am recording a macro in VBA using relative references, I first select cell A1. The code that is generated is this:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "First Cell"
 ActiveCell.Offset(1,1).Range("A1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Second Cell"
 ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Range("A1").Select
```

What I am wondering is why we in the second and fourth cell get ".Range.("A1)"? Should't the relative references behave in such a way that we just start with the starting cell, we could have started somewhere else, so "A1" don't need to appear in the code?
I tried remave ".Range("A1")" from the second line, and the macro seemed to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

When you select a range with relative references turned on, the macro recorder does two things:

1. It determines the offset from the active cell that will be the top-left cell of the newly selected range. If you go from A1 to B1, it builds `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1)` to move zero rows down and one column to the right.
2. It determines the width and height of the newly selected range and builds the command for the height and width in A1 notation. If you go from A1 to B1, it calculates the new range to be 1x1. In A1 notation a 1x1 selection relative to the active cell is "A1", so it continues to build the command as `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Range("A1")`

They had to build the macro recorder to do this in two steps because you could select more than one cell. If you went from A1 to B1:C7. You get

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "First Cell"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:B7").Select
```

That translates into "start in a cell that's zero rows and one column to the right of the active cell, then as if that were the top-left cell of the whole worksheet, select a range two columns wide and seven cells tall.

The confusing part about it is the A1 notation. People only think of cell references like A1 to refer to the whole worksheet. So a reference like C6 will always be the third column and sixth row.

But in VBA, you can use A1 notation starting from any cell. You could select cell K10, then in the Immediate Window enter:

```
?activecell.Range("b2").Range("b2").Range("b2").Address
```

and you would get $N$13. Each of those B2 references mean move one column right and one row down. Three of them in a row does that three times. The key to this is that it starts with a `Range` object, namely `ActiveCell`. If you started with a sheet, like `Sheet1` or `ActiveSheet`, then the A1 notation would be relative the top-left of the sheet.

*Why does it work without it?*

It only works without the `Range("A1")` piece if you select a single cell. If you select more than one cell, you can still remove the Range piece, but the code won't work the same.

Another important reason it works without the Range piece is because the `Offset` property returns a `Range` object. There are a lot of properties that return `Range` objects including `Range`, `Offset`, `Resize`, and `Cells`. Any property that returns a `Range` object can be followed by `.Select` because `Select` is a property of the `Range` object.

*Why does the recorder include it for single cells?*

Nobody knows except the programmer who created the macro recorder. They could have just as easily computed that the newly selected range was a single cell and stopped at `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select`, but it was probably just easier to do both steps regardless of the height and width of the new selection.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this. What is the meaning when we have ".Range("A1")" after the offset? What does this code actually do? As I said it seemed to work without this part of the code aswell?

Comment: Another thing is that I do not press enter after write "First cell", I use the mouse to go to cell B1. I tried highlighting the cells you mentioned before choosing B1, but the code stayed the same.

Comment: I updated the answer to expand on the explanation. When I enter something in A1 and select B1:C7 I get the code in the answer. I did it in Excel to get the code and confirm it works how I expect. I'm not sure why you would be getting something different.